# Hypothesis testing to compare 2 bernoulli processes that generate purchase data

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, bernoulli-distribution

I have 2 large samples from a population of users that checkout from our product offering website and generate certain sales, say r1 and r2. Each sample is from using a different price, say r1=\$20 and r2=\$30. The probability of purchase is of course different from each group. Say the first group has a purchase probability p1 of 0.4 based on large historical n samples, where n >> 10,000. For the second group, we have much fewer observations, on the order of 100-500.

I'm looking for the right statistical test to determine whether the total revenue is higher on the second group. A classical chi-squared test to test whether the underlying 2 bernoulli probabilities are different is not enough, because that test will show that the probabilities are indeed different.

I think I need to determine whether the probability p2 is at least greater by the relative different of the price difference. In this case if r1=\$20 and r2=\$30, and p1 is 0.4, I'm trying to determine if p2 is confidently at least greater than $p1/(r2/r1)$ or $0.4/(30/20)=0.2667%$.

What is the right statistical test for this case?

To make it even more concrete, the hypothetical data is roughly formatted follows:

| group | visits | conversions | total_sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| s1 | 775 | 310 | 6,200 |
| s2 | 240 | 72 | 2,160 |

Another way of framing it would be: what test to determine which population has a higher `total_sales per visit`?